# Why do we take $\epsilon=1$ when proving the boundedness of a convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Could someone explain why, when we want to prove the boundedness of a convergent sequence, we take the $\epsilon$ to be 1, and use it in $r = \{1, d(p_1, p), \ldots, d(p_N, p)\}$ saying that $d(p_n, p) < r$.

Why 1?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about. Giving an example would be very helpful.

Comment: Probably because $1$ is the first positive number which comes to mind if we are free to choose any positive number. But you can take $\sqrt{2}$ if you like.

Comment: Why not? On a side note, $d(x,y)<1$ looks nicer than say $d(x,y)<\sqrt 2$ or $d(x,y)<e^{-\pi ^2+1}$

Comment: @ZevChonoles oh, sorry you're right. i was trying to rush. the proof im talking about is the proof in Rudin's book page49, about a sequence that is convergent and we want to prove the sequence is bounded as well. in the proof we jump into it by saying "There is an integer N such that n > N implies d(p_n, p) < 1. Put r = max{1, d(p_1, p), ... ,d(p_N, p)}; then d(p_n, p) <r. proving its boundedness

Comment: i'm just trying to figure out the reasoning behind the proof. every proof must has some idea behind it which I wish to understand so I can use it in my own proofs later on. so it's random?

Comment: Well, you've just written the essential point of the proof down. The choice of $1$ is somewhat arbitrary, but thw point is that if we go far enough along the sequence, the largest absolute value of the remaining terms can be no more than $1$ greater than the largest absolute value attained so far. Any other strictly positive number could be used in the proof, but $1$ does the job.

Comment: in fact, i do see now that it is quite arbitrary. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just simple for typing. In fact, $\epsilon$ could be any numbers (of course $> 0$ ) to prove that the boundedness of a convergent sequence. I can offered a proof for you:

> **Proof:** Suppose that $\{p_n: n\in \mathbb{N^+}\}$ is a convergent sequence which converges to $p$. Therefore, for any $\epsilon$, there exists $N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N^+}$, such that for any $n>N$, we have $d(p,p_n)<\epsilon$. In particular, we coule take $\epsilon=1$. (In fact, we coule take $\epsilon=2,or,3,....$). Finally, just as you do, we can let $r= \max\{1, d(p,p_1),d(p,p_2),...d(p,p_{N(1)}\}$, which may lead the result which you desired.